# Add shade to block

Tags: html, css

Hello I have several li elements with images and text ( text on image ), and I want to add shade over image ( I want to get dark image and normal text )

My html

```
<li>
    <div class="block-news-textoverlay text-center">
        <h2>
            Lorem ipsum
        </h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</p>
    </div>
    <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
</li>
```

My css

```
.block-news-textoverlay {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 75px;
    padding-right: 75px;
}
```

So I try to add div with "shade" class to li element

```
<li>
    <div class="shade">
        <div class="block-news-textoverlay text-center">
            <h2>
                Lorem ipsum
            </h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</p>
        </div>
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</li>
```

and use css

```
.shade{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0, #000000 130%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using background image and a pseudo element.

```css
.block-news-textoverlay {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 75px;
  padding-right: 75px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-800-800-6.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
}
.block-news-textoverlay:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="block-news-textoverlay text-center">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</p>
  </div>
</li>
```